# Bitmap not working with ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, android-bitmap

I have been attempting to make a listview display icons as well as images based on information pulled from Parse. Everything except the images are set when being used inside of my BaseAdapter. The image, a bitmap, will not appear and just shows a blank space. Here's what i've done so far:

MainActivity.java (Extends ListActivity)

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereNotEqualTo("username", "~");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // The query was successful.

                ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

                    ParseFile picture = objects.get(i).getParseFile("profilepicture");

                    picture.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                if (data.length == 0) {
                                    // data found, but nothing to extract. bad image or upload?
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is bad. Please Try Again Later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    return;
                                }

                                // SUCCESS
                                // convert data and display in an imageview

                                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    FriendListData fld = new FriendListData();

                    fld.setUsername(objects.get(i).getUsername());
                    fld.setFullname(objects.get(i).getString("name"));
                    fld.setProfilePicture(bmp);

                    myList.add(fld);

                    lvDetail.setAdapter(new FriendBaseAdapter(context, myList));
```

FriendListData.java (Just the Bitmap Code)

```
public Bitmap getProfilePicture(){

    return profilePicture;

}

public void setProfilePicture(Bitmap profilePicture){

    this.profilePicture = profilePicture;

}
```

FriendBaseAdapter.java (The `getView()` and the `detail()`)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_list_item, null, true);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    mViewHolder.fullname = detail(convertView, R.id.fullname, myList.get(position).getFullname());
    mViewHolder.username = detail(convertView, R.id.username,  myList.get(position).getUsername());
    mViewHolder.profilePicture = detail(convertView, R.id.profilepicture, myList.get(position).getProfilePicture());

    return convertView;
}

private ImageView detail(View v, int resId, Bitmap profilepicture){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(resId);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(profilepicture);

    return imageView;

}
```

More code can be shown if requested. I'm not running into any runtime errors with my code, and I am able to pull words down from Parse, so I can't imagine what I'm doing wrong. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can get link image.

```
String linkpicture = objects.get(i).getParseFile("profilepicture").getUrl();
```

after:(https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
 mImageLoader.displayImage(myList.get(position).getProfilePicture(),
                profilePicture ,
                mImageOptions);
```